# need to alow access to docx files

Tags: php, .htaccess

I generate docx files with phpword script, download file, but word say that it is broken, if i right understand the problem is in .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.+?\ [^?]+\.php[?\ ]
RewriteRule \.php$ - [L,R=404]
#RewriteRule test index.php
ErrorDocument 404 /not-found.html
ErrorDocument 403 /not-found.html
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule . index.php [L,QSA]

Options All -Indexes


AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

Comment: Don't guess. Start by inspecting the generated file. Rename it to *.txt if that makes it easier.

Comment: The problem is more likely something in your own code that's corrupting the file that is sent to the user's browser, and nothing to do with the htaccess file